# breeze EntityQuery with .expand shows child entity as blank using BreezeQueryableAttribute

Tags: entity-framework-6, breeze

I've never worked with Breeze before and I'm struggling with getting expand to hydrate my child entity.

Parent Entity (Document):

```
public class Document
{
    public Document()
    {
        Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    }
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }

    public IList<DocumentChunk> Chunks { get; set; }
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public string UserEmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string ResumableIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string SourceIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string P8SourceIdentifier { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }

    public void AddTags(string tags)
    {
        var parsedTags = tags.Split(',');

        foreach (var parsedTag in parsedTags) 
        {
            var parsedKeyValueTag = parsedTag.Split(':');
            Tags.Add(new Tag { Key = parsedKeyValueTag[0], Value = parsedKeyValueTag[1] });
        }
    }

    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Child Entity (Tag):

```
public class Tag
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string TransactionId { get; set; }
    public string TenantId { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationId { get; set; }
    public Int64 DocumentId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DocumentId")]
    [InverseProperty("Tags")]
    public Document Document { get; set; }
}
```

I read the Breeze Web API Controller Documentation:
http://breeze.github.io/doc-net/webapi-controller.html
I put the BreezeControllerAttribute on my controller to use the BreezeQueryableAttribute on my Gets.

```
[BreezeController]
public class DocumentsReadController : ApiController
{
    private readonly EFContextProvider<DocsContext> _contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<DocsContext>();

    [HttpGet]
    public string Metadata()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Metadata();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Document> Documents()
    {
        var items = _contextProvider.Context.Documents.AsNoTracking();

        return items;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<Tag> Tags()
    {
        var items = _contextProvider.Context.Tags.AsNoTracking();

        return items;
    }
}
```

Client Side Javascript:

```
function getDocuments() {
                var manager = new breeze.EntityManager('http://localhost:50795/breeze/documentsread');
                var baseQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Documents')
                    .expand('Tags');
                manager.executeQuery(baseQuery).then(function(data) {
                    $scope.documents = data.results;
                }).catch(function(error) { console.log('Query Error: ' + error)} );
            }
```

When I'm watching on the wire with Fiddler my request is successful but when I look at the JSON Tags is empty.

Just out of curiosity based on the documentation link depicted above I added to  Documents Get

```
[Queryable(AllowedFunctions = System.Web.Http.OData.Query.AllowedFunctions.All)]
```

I watched the wire and sure enough Tags was hydrated but I was getting the UI error described in the documentation.

What do I need to change in order to get Tags hydrated using the BreezeQueryableAttribute? I'm going to keep digging through the documentation but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried without .AsNoTracking?

Comment: That appears to of worked. Yahtzee!

Comment: The AsNoTracking prevents EF from hooking up the navigation properties.